Swift - Unable to access app group storeURL
I'm trying to access a shared store on an app I'm building on Xcode 15.4 with a WidgetKit extension and it runs perfectly fine on the simulator but as soon as I archive it and install it on my actual iPhone for testing purposes, it crashes. The crash log pointed to a function I wrote, specifically getting the URL for the shared storage on the device. It only returns nil.
This is said function
public extension URL {
    /// Returns a URL for the given app group and database pointing to the sqlite database.
    static func storeURL(databaseName: String) -> URL? {
        guard let fileContainer = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.groupname.shared") else {
            fatalError("Shared file container could not be created.")
        }
        return fileContainer.appendingPathComponent("\(databaseName)")
    }
}

Code that handles loading the shared store:
lazy var container: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let storeURL = URL.storeURL(databaseName: "StoredData")
    let storeDescription = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: storeURL!)
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "StoredData")
    container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [storeDescription]
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            Alert(title: Text("Unable to load items"), message: Text("\(error.userInfo)"))
            }
    })
        
    return container
}()

I've got no idea what to do about this. I've verified that the app group name isn't spelt incorrectly (which should have been obvious to me since it works on the simulator) but still no luck

The simulator doesn't enforce the sandbox, so just because it works there, doesn't mean everything is correct.

So is there anything that I can do to check what’s wrong? I'm not sure if I need a developer licence to create App Groups but if I do that's really scummy of Apple. Literally locking aspiring developers out of testing functionality unless they pay a steep yearly fee.

App groups are available at the free tier.  You need to ensure that you have added the entitlement to both your main app and your extension app in Xcode and it has been associated with your provisioning profiles.  Selecting "automatic" signing is the simplest way.

That's the thing though, I've added the app group to both targets in my app with the same name, verified that the group is signed and it STILL won't work. The only place it works is in a simulator.

Did you tried adding .sqlite to the databaseName: "StoredData"?
Try this extension:
/// Returns a URL for the given app group and database pointing to the sqlite database.
/// - Parameters:
///   - appGroup: Appgroup string value
///   - databaseName: What will be the db name
/// - Returns: URL for the shared file
static func storeURL(forAppGroup appGroup: String, withDBName databaseName: String) -> URL? {
    guard let fileContainer = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appGroup) else {
        return nil
    }

    return fileContainer.appendingPathComponent("\(databaseName).sqlite")
}


I'll give this a shot and get back to you. I'm out of App IDs but they'll refresh tomorrow. I'm not too hopeful that this'll work though because the ".sqlite" is an identifier that lets an app know how to read the data inside. Since I'm giving the URL to the NSPersistentStoreDescription it should already be using that as a database filetype

hmmm, I did this extension and CoreDataStack class 3 years ago - can't remember the reason to add the ".sqlite". But it does work - so hopefully it will help you as well
